# Which mathematical subjects simplify another mathematical subject by removing exceptions?

Tags: complex-analysis, projective-geometry

I have often heard it said that complex analysis is in some ways simpler than real analysis (because every differentiable function can be differentiated as many times as we want, and always has a power series expansion). Similarly, many theorems in projective geometry are simpler than their equivalents in euclidean geometry because one doesn't have to deal with the exceptional case of non-intersecting lines.

Are there any other well-known pairs of mathematical topics that bear a similar relationship, where theorems are greatly simplified by the removal of an exceptional case?

Comment: I like this question, but want to clarify about the complex/real statement. Complex analysis feels simpler because we are adding in the complex structure but then *defining* differentiability with respect to complex variables, which is a severely restricted class of functions (compared to real differentiable functions). So it's not so much the removal of an exceptional case as it is an intense restriction on what we can study by the imposition of more structure.

Comment: Zeros of nonconstant polynomials in $\mathbb{R}$ versus $\mathbb{C}$; similarly eigenvalues of matrices. Another kind-of-example is that constrained optimization is typically harder than unconstrained.

Comment: Building on the comments before mine, you can find examples of this everywhere in math we add structure to existing objects - the reason complex analysis is "nicer" is because we give it a more structured derivative. As another example, the category $R$-Mod is far nicer in many aspects than the category Ring, due to it being Abelian (nice for things like diagram chases, simplifies the meaning of epi/mono-morphisms, etc etc)

Answer (score 2):

One example I encountered recently is elliptic geometry as a simplification of spherical geometry. By equating antipodal points, one is able to state “two distinct points make a line” without having to include an exception for the case where the two points are opposite one another on the sphere (such points would no longer be considered distinct).